# Two-level system + bosonic field: an arbitrary choice of operators ordering leads to two different results

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, second-quantization, bosons

I encountered a situation where two seemingly equivalent choices of the ordering of operators lead, after some calculation, to two non-equivalent operator orderings.

Consider the interaction between a two-level system and a continuum of bosonic modes. The simplest Hamiltonian is

$
\hat{H} = \omega_A \hat{\sigma}_+ \hat{\sigma}_- + \int d\omega \; \omega \;\hat{c}^\dagger_\omega \hat{c}_\omega + V \int d\omega \left[ \hat{c}^\dagger_\omega \hat{\sigma}_- + \hat{c}_\omega \hat{\sigma}_+ \right]
$

where $\hat{\sigma}_+, \hat{\sigma}_-, \hat{\sigma}_z$ are the usual Pauli operators to describe a two-level system, and $\hat{c}_\omega, \hat{c}_\omega^\dagger$ are bosonic operators, describing a mode with frequency   $\omega$. $V$ is a coupling coefficient. We can set $\omega_A=0$ for brevity.

We can derive the Heisenberg equation for some of the operators

$ \dot{\hat{\sigma}}_-(t) = + i \int d\omega \hat{c}_\omega(t) \hat{\sigma}_z(t)$

$\dot{\hat{c}}_\omega(t) = - i\omega \hat{c}_\omega(t) - i V \hat{\sigma}_-(t)$

Note that in the first equation the order of the operators $\hat{c}_\omega(t) \hat{\sigma}_z(t)$ does not matter because, by definition, they commute (and Heisenberg evolution preserve the commutation relations). We now use a standard trick, we solve the second equation,

$    \hat{c}_\omega(t) = e^{-i\omega(t-t_0)}\hat{c}_\omega(t_0) - i V \int_{t_0}^t dt' \hat{\sigma}_- (t') e^{-i\omega(t-t')}$

and we plug it in the first (for simplicity I will set $\hat{c}_\omega(t_0)=0$ just because is not relevant to the problem discussed here). We get

$\dot{\hat{\sigma}}_-(t) =  V^2 \int d\omega  \int_{t_0}^t dt' \hat{\sigma}_- (t') e^{-i\omega(t-t')} \hat{\sigma}_z(t)$

Finally, by switching the order of integration, and using $\int d\omega e^{-i\omega(t-t')} = \pi \delta(t-t')$, we get

$\dot{\hat{\sigma}}_- =   \frac{\pi V^2}{2}  \hat{\sigma}_- \hat{\sigma}_z$

where I dropped the time dependence. Here is where I get confused. The operators $\hat{\sigma}_-$ and $\hat{\sigma}_z$ do not commute, so the ordering is important.

However, if we made a different choice for the ordering of the operators $\hat{c}_\omega(t) \hat{\sigma}_z(t)$ (which we can because they commute), we would have obtained  $\hat{\sigma}_z \hat{\sigma}_- $ in the last equation.

What is the "correct" way of choosing the operator order here?
Is this problem somehow related to the normal ordering in quantum field theory?

Comment: "for simplicity I will set $\hat{c}_\omega (t_0)=0$ just because is not relevant to the problem discussed here". I don't think you can do that, and I expect that it will actually matter to your solution. $\hat{c}_\omega$ has to maintain $\hat{c}_\omega(0)=\hat{c}_\omega$. And *at no point in time* can it be equal to zero. The e.o.m for $\sigma_-$ will always have a dependence on $c$

Comment: I agree. What I meant was just that the problem that I have (the non-equivalent order of those two operators) doesn't depend on the presence of $\hat{c}_\omega(t_0)$, so I just removed it to keep the equations shorter and get quickly to my main problem.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you must preserve is the fact that

$$\sigma^\dagger_\pm(t)=\sigma_\mp(t)$$

which clearly won’t necessarily happen because of the ambiguity you noticed.

One way to force it, instead of assuming commutation relation between $c$ and $\sigma$, is to assume they don’t commute by a small $\epsilon$ which you’ll send to zero at the end of calculations;

This way, you are forced to introduce both terms $\frac{c\sigma+\sigma c+\epsilon}2$ and your result should be all consistent;

Comment: Thanks, but I am still confused. I agree that with that assumption now we are sure that $\sigma^\dagger_\pm(t)=\sigma_\mp(t)$ always holds.
But now I obtain 
$\dot{\hat{\sigma}}_- =   \frac{\pi V^2}{2}  \frac{\hat{\sigma}_- \hat{\sigma}_z+\hat{\sigma}_z\hat{\sigma}_- }{2}$

Which is yet a different result from either $\dot{\hat{\sigma}}_- =   \frac{\pi V^2}{2}  \hat{\sigma}_- \hat{\sigma}_z$ or $\dot{\hat{\sigma}}_- =   \frac{\pi V^2}{2}  \hat{\sigma}_z \hat{\sigma}_- $.

Comment: Moreover,$\sigma^\dagger_\pm(t)=\sigma_\mp(t)$ can be satisfied by choosing, for example 
$\dot{\hat{\sigma}}_- =   \frac{\pi V^2}{2}  \hat{\sigma}_- \hat{\sigma}_z$
and
$\dot{\hat{\sigma}}_+ =   \frac{\pi V^2}{2}   \hat{\sigma}_z \hat{\sigma}_+$

or alternatively 
$\dot{\hat{\sigma}}_- =   \frac{\pi V^2}{2}  \hat{\sigma}_z  \hat{\sigma}_-$
and
$\dot{\hat{\sigma}}_+ =   \frac{\pi V^2}{2}   \hat{\sigma}_+ \hat{\sigma}_z $

So it looks to me that I still have some freedom in the initial choice, which then leads to two physically different results.

Comment: Yes, that term is as different from the other results you mention, as $\frac12\{\hat x,\hat p\}$ is different from $\hat x\hat p$ or $\hat p\hat x$. In that case, the requirement of the Hamiltonian to be Hermitian imposes you to use $\frac12\{\hat x,\hat p\}$ and not one of $\hat x\hat p$/$\hat p\hat x$. In this case the (fictitious) requirement of keeping the Hamiltonian Hermitian after the introduction of the fictitious commutation relation, would solve the ambiguity.

Comment: From a physical standpoint, if this model is to represent some real system, it will be experiments to tell you if the $\sigma_z\sigma_-$ or the $\sigma_-\sigma_z$ is the one to be used, _if we expect it to have a physical observable effect_. Maybe the most general Hamiltonian would not even be the one I wrote, $\frac{c\sigma+\sigma c}{2}$, but instead $\alpha_1 c\sigma+\alpha_2 \sigma c$ where $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ will measure the weight of each possibility in physical results

Comment: Also, one last thing, as $\sigma_z$ and $\sigma_-$ anticommute, are you sure that the fact that you get $\dot \sigma_- \propto\sigma_z \sigma_-$ and $\dot \sigma_- \propto \sigma_-\sigma_z\equiv-\sigma_z \sigma_-$ isn't an indicator that $\dot \sigma_-$ must vanish?

Comment: Thanks for all the interesting insight. Here I'm trying to describe a two-level atom coupled to a waveguide (bosonic field). Eventually, I would expect to obtain $\dot \sigma_- \propto -\sigma_-$, as the coupling to the waveguide should add a loss channel, and $\dot \sigma_- \propto -\sigma_-$ is what I would obtain if I apply blindly the Heisenberg-Lindlblad equation with Lindblad operator $\propto \sigma_-$

Comment: that sounds interesting! I wish I could give you some more help but outside of some blatant rambling over first principles i become somewhat dumb 